# How to simplify first several factors of an expression, without trying to simplify the rest?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a long expression of the form

```
-(1/(12 M (2 + M - M ζ^2 - η^2))) (-2 + M (-1 + ζ^2) + η^2)(some long expr)
```

The expression is a result of a Mathematica command. ([Here's the expression itself](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8982202), for the reference.) The long expression `(some long expr)` is a polynomial in ζ and η, and, if simplified, the whole expression would also be a (product of) polynomial(s) — unlike its form above, which is a ratio of polynomials.

The first two factors can be simplified by `Simplify` successfully, but, when applied to the full expression, it leaves them unchanged. I tried `FullSimplify` on the full expression, but I couldn't wait until it finishes.

I'd like to direct Mathematica to simplify the first two factors to `1/(12 M)`, without touching the rest, so that the result would be

```
1/(12 M)(some long expr)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried [`Together`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Together.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a function for that long expression and specify that as an excluded form in `Simplify`.

```
someLongExp[x_] = Expand[(1 + x)^100, x]
Simplify[-(1/(12 M (2 + M - M ζ^2 - η^2))) (-2 + M (-1 + ζ^2) + η^2) someLongExp[x],
 ExcludedForms -> {someLongExp[_]}]
```

**Edit**

As pointed out by @bbgodfrey, it does not work for all cases (for example, when `someLongExp[x_] = 2 Expand[(1 + x)^100, x]`). As suggested by @bbgodfrey, this can be resolved by using `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` as follows.

```
someLongExp[x_] = 2 Expand[(1 + x)^100, x] // Hold;
Simplify[-(1/(12 M (2 + M - M ζ^2 - η^2))) (-2 + M (-1 + ζ^2) + η^2) someLongExp[x], 
  ExcludedForms -> {someLongExp[_]}] // ReleaseHold
```

Another way is by using `TimeConstraint`to force `Simplify` to use only the basic simplification rules.

```
Quiet@Simplify[-(1/(12 M (2 + M - M ζ^2 - η^2))) (-2 + M (-1 + ζ^2) + η^2) someLongExp[x],
TimeConstraint -> 0.0001]
```

Comment: This elegant solution works for the example given but not for `2 Expand[(1 + x)^100, x]` and for some other instances.  This problem can be circumvented by using `Hold` on the right side of the first line, and `\\ ReleaseHold` at the end of the second line of code.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: But what if the whole expression is the output of another command, not something you just enter/copy-paste?

Comment: @Ruslan Can you clarify by giving an example.

Comment: Do you mean an example of the full expression or the commands which generate it? The commands are quite long, so I don't think they'll be really useful for you. But the expression — yes, I can post it.

Comment: @Ruslan I think by limiting the simplification time using `TimeConstraint`, we can force `Simplify` to use only the basic simplification rules. The above solution can be modified as follows. 
`Quiet@Simplify[-(1/(12 M (2 + M - M ζ^2 - η^2))) (-2 + M (-1 + ζ^2) + η^2) someLongExp[x], 
  TimeConstraint -> 0.0001]`

Comment: Yeah, `TimeConstraint` did the job. For reference, [here's the expression](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8982202).

Comment: I would not count on `TimeConstrained` working reliably for this purpose.